# How to show current mode in status-line in tmux?

Tags: vim, tmux

In `vim`: `:set showcmd` tells me what key I've typed(such as <kbd>f</kbd>).

In `tmux`: after typing <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd>, I stop to think about the next key I need.
Sometimes I forgot I've typed <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd>, so I type it again, it causes problem.

How to change the status-line to let me know I've typed <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd>?

Comment: I don't think there is a way, although it sounds like a good feature to add to `tmux`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone still looking for a solution, you can know when you have typed the `tmux prefix`, by adding this to your statusline:

```
#{?client_prefix,#[fg=colour2]^A,}
```

When added to status line, you will get a nice little `^A` inside your tmux statusline when you press your prefix. Please, change colour and prefix message accordingly.

You can go fancy, and even toggle all bg colors in your statusline when `prefix` is typed.

```
set -g status-left "#{?client_prefix,#[bg=colour2],#[bg=colour1]}#[fg=colour0] #S "
```

Answer (score 1):

As [chepner](https://superuser.com/users/126224/chepner) already said [here](https://superuser.com/questions/429577/how-to-show-current-mode-in-status-line-in-tmux#comment494174_429577), no options to show currently typed keys or prefixes seem to exist (nor are mentioned in the manpage).

As a workaround, you can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> before you use the prefix <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd> again. This way you will discard any previously typed (forgotten) prefixes and avoid accidentally sending multiple <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd>.